# Django: Display images from dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a dictionary in `views.py` which contains `track_id` and `image_path`. For each `track_id` there could be one or more `image_path`, hence it is a dictionary where values are passed as the list.

Example representation:

```
{0: ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'], 1: ['3.jpg'], 2: ['4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']}
```

How can I display images on HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dictionary is passed to your template as `track_images`:

```
{% for track_id, image_paths in track_images.items %}
   <div>
     <h1>Track {{ track_id }}</h1>
     {% for image_path in image_paths %}
        <img src="{{ image_path }}" >
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The timer stuff is not Django-related.

Comment: Sure thing for the timer stuff. I will have a look for that. Thanks, let me try this code.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I will ask seperate question for timer stuff. Cheers !

Comment: I will edit question and remove timer stuff so that it won't confuse someone if they look for the question. Also, I can't accept right now, I will check do that later. Thanks again